# Log4j2 can't found log42j.xml in other location instead classpath (resource folder) Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, log4j2

I am developing a java web-app (v3.0) for a TomCat 9.0 server and I am having troubles loading the log4j2.xml file.

I have defined the log4j2.xml file outside my project and defined the path for the file in my web.xml file.

I have configured the path in web.xml file as follows but when running tomcat I get this error 'ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default configuration: logging only errors to the console.'

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>file:///E:/logtest/log4j2.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Please help me
I have followed the instructions in the Log4j2 docs correctly, I don't know what I am missing to be able to run it.

Comment: *I have defined the log4j2.xml file outside my project* Why so?

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the [documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/webapp), you need to:

- add `log4j-web` to your classpath,
- set a value to the `log4jConfiguration` parameter (not `log4jConfigLocation`):

  ```xml
  <context-param>
      <param-name>log4jConfiguration</param-name>
      <param-value>file:///E:/logtest/log4j2.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>
  ```